# How can we shutdown or disable mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables created in a database. I want to disable one of the tables so that no operations(CRUD) can be performed on it. Is there any mysql commands we can use to achieve this?

Comment: Revoke insert / update / delete access to the given table? Or just delete or rename it?

Comment: @Shadow I want to maintain the table .Don't want to delete or rename it.

Answer (score 1):

The REVOKE command allows you to remove privileges from an account.

REVOKE <privileges> ON <database>.<object> FROM '<user>'@'<host>';

Example:

REVOKE INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON <database>.<object> FROM '<user>'@'<host>';